# Particle current operator in tight binding

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, hamiltonian-formalism, many-body, tight-binding

For general non-interacting Hamiltonian $H = \frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\int dr \Psi_r^\dagger\nabla_r^2\Psi_r$, the particle current operator $J$ can be derived using continuety equation $\nabla_r\cdot J = -\partial_t \rho=-\frac{i}{\hbar}[H,\Psi_r^\dagger\Psi_r]$. It is given as:
$$
J = \frac{\hbar}{2mi}[\Psi_r^\dagger\nabla_r\Psi_r-(\nabla_r\Psi_r^\dagger)\Psi_r] \tag{1}
$$

Now, let's write non-interacting Hamiltonian in tight-binding form (with nearest-neighbor hopping only):
$$
H = -2t\sum_{k}\cos(k)c_k^\dagger c_{k} 
$$
and apply basis transformation for $c_k$ operator to field operators  (Eq. 1.73 of Henrik Bruus Book)
$$
c_k^\dagger = \frac{1}{\sqrt{V}} \int dr e^{ikr} \Psi_r
$$
we get:
$$
H = -\frac{t}{V}\sum_{k}\int dr dr'\Psi_r^\dagger \Psi_{r'} e^{ikr}e^{-ikr'}(e^{ik}+e^{-ik})\\
H = -t\int dr (\Psi_r^\dagger \Psi_{r+1} + \Psi_{r+1}^\dagger \Psi_{r})
$$
now to find the current operator, apply the continuity equation. The commutator will give zero as follows:
$$
[H,\Psi_{s}^\dagger\Psi_{s}]=-t\int dr ([\Psi_{r}^\dagger\Psi_{r+1},\Psi_{s}^\dagger\Psi_{s}]+[\Psi_{r+1}^\dagger\Psi_{r},\Psi_{s}^\dagger\Psi_{s}])\\
=-t\int dr (\Psi_{r}^\dagger[\Psi_{r+1},\Psi_{s}^\dagger]\Psi_{s}+
\Psi_{s}^\dagger [\Psi_{r}^\dagger,\Psi_{s}]\Psi_{r+1}+
\Psi_{r+1}^\dagger[\Psi_{r},\Psi_{s}^\dagger]\Psi_{s}+
\Psi_{s}^\dagger[\Psi_{r+1}^\dagger,\Psi_{s}]\Psi_{r})\\
=-t(\Psi_{r}^\dagger\Psi_{r+1}-
\Psi_{r}^\dagger \Psi_{r+1}+
\Psi_{r+1}^\dagger\Psi_{r}-
\Psi_{r+1}^\dagger\Psi_{r})\\
=0
$$

What is wrong with this calculation? Should not I be able to get the same formula as given in equation (1)?

*What I was hoping for:*

I thought I will get terms like $\Psi_r^\dagger(\Psi_{r+1}-\Psi_{r})$. And then in continus limit, I can assume that $\Psi_{r+1}-\Psi{r}=\nabla_r \Psi_r$. Which will give me something like $\Psi_r^\dagger\nabla \Psi_r$ terms.

Does second quantization and quantum mechanics allow this kind of simplifications?

Comment: How are you evaluating the commutators? Fermions have anicommutation relations, but you seem to be assuming they obey the bosonic relations

Comment: @JahanClaes Ooooo my god. I totally missed it. I will rederive everything.
By the way, does it mean that Bosons don't have current operators?